# Bundling some information with an executable?

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis-7.5, clickonce

I'm using IIS 7.5 on my webserver, and I am creating a C# WPF program that I publish to that server, so that people can download the program.

Right now, people download the program using `http://.../Software/Shapeshifter/Setup.exe`

However, I would like editors from magazines and so on to be able to make a branded copy of my program, so that they can choose to brand it.

For instance this link:
`http://.../Software/Shapeshifter/Setup.exe?brandName=test&brandImage=http://uriToImage.example.com`

And then read that from my program when it starts, to brand the application properly.

Currently I am using ClickOnce to do this, since it allows web invocation of such arguments. However, it only works properly in Internet Explorer.

I've been considering the following scenario to solve it:

1. Make a .EXE file HttpHandler.
2. When a .EXE file is requested, check the parameters.
3. Somehow embed the parameters into the .EXE file (how would I do this?)
4. Read the parameters from the application (again, how would I do this?)

To make it all a bit more easy, let's just say that my my program is a single .EXE file, and that Setup.exe is actually the program's executable file itself, without any wrapper installers (even though that's not the case).

Any suggestions?

Comment: Maybe you should ask for yourself are there alternatives to [ClickOnce](https://www.google.nl/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ie=UTF-8&ion=1#hl=nl&newwindow=1&safe=off&sclient=psy-ab&q=clickonce%20alternatives&oq=ClickOnce%20alternative&gs_l=hp.3.1.0l2j0i5i30l2.2711.19030.0.20841.39.33.4.0.0.5.229.2335.27j5j1.33.0...0.0...1c.1.JqUGaKFtjWY&pbx=1&fp=1&ion=1&biw=1280&bih=939&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.r_cp.r_qf.&cad=b)

Comment: You could "simulate" the steps that your Visual Studio does when you compile. E.g. manually compile and link resources (images, strings) into your executable and that stuff.

Comment: How about making a self-extracting zip file on the fly, and including the configurable stuff in the archive? If you can find something to zip to exe that can also launch something inside the zip, you're in business.

Answer (score 1):

Honestly, I would first just compile a huge string resource in the EXE, something that can be easily identified (very specific HEX combinations), open the EXE as binary file, search for this location and put any data in there. Not exactly beautiful, but should work.

But after a deep digging around the web I finally found a resource editor that is both free and supports execution from command line.

The tool is [Resource Hacker](http://www.angusj.com/resourcehacker/).
The command line usage is described in the [tutorial](http://www.askvg.com/tutorial-all-about-resource-hacker-in-a-brief-tutorial/) (search for "Using Scripts in Resource Hacker")

Comment: I like this approach. I used to replace Windows boot-screens with it before. As long as it works good via command-line, that is. Although, this might be a problem if the code is signed?

Comment: Delay signing should solve it: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t07a3dye(VS.80).aspx. There are other topics covering re-signing an application.